# SQL Query for finding SNAP ID using database startup time

Tags: sql, join

I want to find the minimum and maximum `SNAP_ID` for same duration of database startup time. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
select snap_id,BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME, startup_time 
from dba_hist_snapshot 
where trunc(end_interval_time) > (SELECT trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'FRIDAY')) -14 FROM dual) 
  AND trunc(end_interval_time) <= (SELECT trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'SUNDAY')) -7 FROM dual) 
order by snap_id;
```

In this query the table name is `dba_hist_snapshot`, `snap_id` is primary key, `startup_time` is attribute

```
SNAP_ID BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME          STARTUP_TIME
70661   24-JUL-15 11.00.13.576 PM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70662   25-JUL-15 12.00.29.582 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70663   25-JUL-15 01.00.45.213 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70664   25-JUL-15 02.00.00.592 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70665   25-JUL-15 03.00.15.646 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70666   25-JUL-15 04.00.30.730 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70667   25-JUL-15 05.00.46.230 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70668   25-JUL-15 06.00.01.187 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70669   25-JUL-15 07.00.16.430 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70670   25-JUL-15 08.00.31.673 AM    18-JUL-15 02.29.24.000 PM
70671   25-JUL-15 12.29.47.000 PM    25-JUL-15 12.29.47.000 PM
70672   25-JUL-15 12.40.34.973 PM    25-JUL-15 12.29.47.000 PM
70673   25-JUL-15 02.27.06.000 PM    25-JUL-15 02.27.06.000 PM
70674   25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70675   25-JUL-15 04.00.34.965 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70676   25-JUL-15 05.00.49.120 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70677   25-JUL-15 06.00.03.588 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70678   25-JUL-15 07.00.17.985 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70679   25-JUL-15 08.00.32.356 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70680   25-JUL-15 09.00.47.711 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
70681   25-JUL-15 10.00.02.117 PM    25-JUL-15 03.44.54.000 PM
```

I want the output as : Min Snap id->70661, Max Snap id->70670

Comment: Google and learn about the MIN() and MAX() functions in SQL.

Comment: Actually in my question database startup time is changing......so i need to find the last snap id before changed startup time...

Comment: Yes, you also need to learn about the GROUP BY clause, but that will almost certainly be mentioned in any tutorial about MIN and MAX.

Comment: Your sample results don't seem to match what you're asking for, wouldn't you want a startup time in there as well?  Also, is interval time required?

Comment: Hey Gary, Thanks for your response. no i don't want startup time in my output. By previous query i was able to generate the above table. Acutally i need to find the snap id (min and max). In Mid level -Output you can see that database startup time is changing (i.e changed from 18 jul to 25 jul), I want the snap id of database where time just got changed.

Answer (score 0):

There's two real things to address here.  First is to find the minimum startup time in the range you're interested in.

```
 SELECT MIN(startup_time) 
  FROM dba_hist_snapshot 
  where trunc(end_interval_time) > (trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'FRIDAY')) -14) 
  AND trunc(end_interval_time) <= (trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'SUNDAY')) -7)
```

Then you find the range of snap_id's that relate to that particular start up time, giving something like

```
SELECT MIN(snap_id), MAX(snap_id)
FROM dba_hist_snapshot 
WHERE startup_time IN
 (SELECT MIN(startup_time) 
  FROM dba_hist_snapshot 
  where trunc(end_interval_time) > (trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'FRIDAY')) -14) 
  AND trunc(end_interval_time) <= (trunc(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'SUNDAY')) -7) )
```

Comment: Thanks Bro,working like a charm. Appreciate your effort.